# How do commands like, make and make install, affect Debian packaging system?

Tags: compilation

I will give an example so I can explain my question properly. I am trying to compile from source latest blender on debian wheezy 64 bit. There are many dependencies i have to install for a proper build procedure.

I started to install those dependencies but some of them conflict with other packages on my system or some packages are not available on wheezy repositories, only on testing or unstable. After breaking my system by adding testing and unstable and re-installing debian, I started building those dependencies from source. For example, i compiled python from source.

The compile-process i know is :

```
./configure
make
make install
```

How does it affect packaging system? Is there any way keeping this compile-procedure from affecting it? For example if building blender from source requires openimageio libraries, Can i install those libraries locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can. Normally, you precise their locations as parameters to ./configure and sometimes they are declared as environment variables. See the build documentation for your package.

Comment: So I can install Libraries locally. What about dependencies? Are they local too? For example, If i compile python3.4 in a folder in my home directory, does it affect my packaging system or not?

Comment: The compilation that happens in your folder remains in your folder.